# EF foreign key is NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following model class:

```
[key]
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CustomerType")]
public int? CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
public virtual CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }

[Key]
public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
public string CustomerTypeCode { get; set; }
```

Then I want to load it into a view with this controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     var obj = _db.Customer.Include(i => i.CustomerType);
     return View(await obj.ToListAsync());
}
```

On the view:

```
@using IEnumerable<myProject.Models.Customer>
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Customer
     <th>CustomerType
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
   <tr>
     <td>@item.Customer</td>
     <td>@item.CustomerType.Code</td>
   </tr>
   }
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I tried to run it, I get an error for `@item.CustomerType.Code` because the data is null in the database:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Does anyone know why? Even I tried to put `?` on the model, it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to your code some of records from `Customer` might not be have a `CustomerType`. And this is your case: `item.CustomerType` is `null`. Add check for `null` or define `public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }` depend on your data design.

Comment: So whats your expectation handle with null data or don't bind null data into table? Which one you want?

Comment: @Jackdaw Yes, some of customers will have no CustomerType. I put `?` in the model. But again, it appears the error. How can I handle it?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, I want to handle with null data. So it will blank on the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply cool, wait a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well keeping all the existing code I found this solution for you. Just need to change a bit on your view. No changes on controller.

***Models:***

```cs
public class Customer
    {
        [key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerType")]
        public int? CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    }

public class CustomerType
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerTypeCode { get; set; }
      
    }
```

***Controller:***

```cs
  public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerIndex()
        {
            var obj = _context.Customers.Include(i => i.CustomerType);
            return View(await obj.ToListAsync());
        }
```

***View:***

```cs
@model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.Customer>
<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer
            <th>Customer Type
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.CustomerName</td>
                <td>@(item.CustomerType == null ? "" : item.CustomerType.CustomerTypeCode)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> ***Note:*** There are few other way to handle this scenario from controller side but this one I think more less code and easiest way.  `<td>@item.CustomerType?.CustomerTypeCode</td>` this also would work but I prefer to use `ternary` operator here

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. But the error still the same.

Comment: I found a solution. I just need to put `?` on it... `@item.CustomerType?.CustomerTypeCode` .... and it works.

Comment: My solution should works exacly, only `?` on model doesn't work exactly, you have to check null value. `<td>@(item.CustomerType == null ? "" : item.CustomerType.CustomerTypeCode)</td>`  this is the way, It shouldn't get error, I double you placed it correctly. See the full updated answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct! perfect! Thanks a lot. Really appreciated.

Comment: Glad to assist on this

Comment: Additionally, `@item.CustomerType?.CustomerTypeCode` this on views should also work, but I preffer to use `tarnary` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You Just Add,

[Required]

Property